# LWC Custom Font - Failed to decode

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css, font

Not sure where my error is here. It's failing to decode my .woff font, but I have absolutely no idea why. Not getting a 404, so it's finding the font but..eh. Any ideas?

Static resource is
fonts/halimun-font/HalimunW.woff for the path. I've tried putting /fonts/halimun-font, and just /fonts/HalimunW, but nothing seems to fix the error here. I'm just trying to get a handwritten script for my LWC text. There's also a css file in the fonts folder.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Halimun';
    src: url('halimun-font/HalimunW.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.customClass {
    font-family: 'Halimun';
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import sResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fonts';

export default class AppointmentLetter extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback() {
        loadStyle(this, sResource + '/style.css')
          .then(() => {});
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you provide the directory structure of the static resource? or, are you able to provide a link to the font zip folder that you are using? I suspect the problem should be with the way you are loading the custom style.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help. The directory structure of the static resource is: fonts/halimun-font/HalimunW.woff with fonts as the static resource name itself

Comment: Is this available as a free download? Note that I can google out bunch of halimun fonts out there for download, but I'm trying to stick with the one you have used. My intent is to try out this at my end before I make any further comments.